# button Onclick function with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a button using woocommerce for each product, when clicked on it is meant to dropdown a form with its corresponding ID. I'm using woocommerce for displaying the products, and gravity forms for the forms.

I have placed this code html code to create the function for the button :

```
       <div class="dropdown">
       <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">SPECIFY PRODUCT</button>
       <div id="gform_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="dropdown-content">
       <?php gravity_form( 1, false, false, false, '', true ); ?>
       </div>
       </div>
```

I also have the script above this html block (as i tried putting in the head section but was giving me a 'null is not an object error' for the document.GetElem...)

```
       <script>
       var theid = "<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>";

       function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById('gform_' + theid).classList.toggle('show');
       }
       </script>
```

When i go to click on either of the 3 buttons it only drops down on the 3rd (pulling that ID first and not getting the others).

How can I make all the buttons dropdown and not just one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to work this out for a while now..

Here is the link: http://www.ctagroup.com.au/cta-group-home/products/tactile-guidance/suresteel/suresteel-classic/

Comment: I'm doing thing from phone but I guess you can try passing the ID in the function

Comment: https://jsbin.com/vahaqozehi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: That solution would be appropriate for only a handful of products, i was originally going to do that but there will be over 500 products. Therefor i would have to create 500 ID's..
@Ashar

Comment: try putting your script above the `<div class="dropdown">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the code below:

```js
<script>
function myFunction(myid) {
 document.getElementById('gform_' + myid).classList.toggle('show');
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>)" class="dropbtn">SPECIFY PRODUCT</button>
 <div id="gform_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="dropdown-content">
  <?php gravity_form( 1, false, false, false, '', true ); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @vqianduan  
it worked, once i put the variable id in the content-product file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element's next sibling

```
 function myFunction(el) {
     el.nextSibling.classList.toggle('show');
 }


 <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">SPECIFY PRODUCT</button>
```

Comment: I have tried this also. Must i take out the document.getElementById tag?
http://i.imgur.com/qQJjSPy.png?1
@Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I'll present a jQuery solution because I'm more comfortable with it than with regular JS. WooCommerce already uses it so the library is already loaded.

I would drop the `onclick()` from your HTML and rely on class-based selectors. I'm making the assumption that you only want to drop down the form that relates to the button clicked.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">SPECIFY PRODUCT</button>
    <div id="gform_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="dropdown-content">
        <?php gravity_form( 1, false, false, false, '', true ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then my jQuery (which you only need once in the footer) would look like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.dropbtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Here's an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01j2b3ne/1/)